# Normal map not baking properly--half of the model is baked in the wrong direction

Tags: texturing, uv, normals, baking

New to blender, so I could be doing a lot wrong here.

I've baked my normal maps in Cycles render, but parts of them are flipped the wrong way. There are awful seams on the tail and legs and I'm at a loss now of what to try next.

What can cause this and how can I fix it?[image]

[image]

Comment: Are normals of the mesh pointing in the same direction? Edit mode > select all > Ctrl+N. How does normal map actually work once applied to lowpoly?

Comment: All the normals are working properly. From what I can tell, it's a problem with the way Blender is deciding to bake. The left side of the tail should be on the right side and the right should be on the left. But when I paint my texture everything works just as you'd expect it to. So if it's not a problem with the normals and not a problem with the UVs, it's gotta be the renderer right? I'd like to learn from this but it seems to me that the best option might be to pop it into photoshop and reverse the normals manually?

Comment: Can you show screenshot of your mesh in the solid shading, Edit mode? *"it's a problem with the way Blender is deciding to bake"* if this is true it should've worked this way for all baking normals cases as well while it doesn't. What version of Blender do you use?

Comment: I've added a photo to the post. I use version 2.79

Comment: Does it mean highpoly normals are also facing outside? Is scale for both objects applied? (Object mode > Ctrl+A). I suppose this artifact happens on the seam on the UV map. Do places with other seams have the same? If you can share some parts of the model with problem upload it here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and hopefully someone can spot the problem

Comment: When you modeled the object, did you create the tail and the body separately? If so make sure that you remove doubles to avoid having geometry that is not really connected.

Comment: Yes I've applied scale and it's still got the bad seams. And yes, this problem appears on pretty much every seam. I've seen similar problems online but none quite like mine, nothing I've found online has helped. I will post on your link though, thank you very much for that!

Comment: Unfortunately my file is too large and it doesn't accept .zips. Is there anywhere else I can post?

Comment: Create a simplified version of the file with only piece of the concerned model where the problem is apparent (on the place of a seam). Then upload blend itself to blend-exchange